# Classic ASP - connect to PHPMyAdmin MySQL database - is it possible?

Tags: mysql, database, vbscript, phpmyadmin, asp-classic

I created a database with PHPMyAdmin. I have the IP address of the PHPMyAdmin web server. I also have the name of the database, as well as the login credentials (username and password) to log in and access the database.

Here is the thing though - my ASP code is another web server, not the PHPMyAdmin web server.

Would it still be possible for me to access the database in the PHPMyAdmin web server from another web server? (Both have different IP addresses).

If so, how would I do that?

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="PHPMyAdmin"
conn.Open ""
```

In the classic ASP code above, I am not sure if I am calling the provider correctly. I am also not sure what to put inside the conn.Open quotes.

If what I am trying to do is feasible, how should I change the code above?

For security reasons (and other reasons I'd rather not go into), I cannot store my ASP code in my PHPMyAdmin web server.

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyadmin isn't a database connector, it's an application written in php which enables you to administer a MySql database.

You can connect to MySql with Classic ASP.  First you need to install the MyODBC connector on your webserver then you can use a connection string like this

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};Server=[address/ip of database server];Database=yourDB;User=yourUsername;Password=yourPW;Option=3;"
```

The connection string will depend on which version of the driver you have installed, see [this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

As the database and website are on different servers, you'll need to make sure that the MySQL port on your database server - usually 3306 - accepts external connections

If you're on shared hosting then you need to ask tech support if the MyODBC driver is installed, and which version

`